# How to get data individually from List View childs in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created an activity which shows data like a shopping application where product is on left and + and - signs are at right.

I have created a new class to create the + and - so that they can work independently on clicking and called in the main class.

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  CounterState createState() => new CounterState();
}

class CounterState extends State<Counter> {

  int itemCount = 0;

  int totalCost= 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child:  Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            itemCount!=0 ?new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline, size: 30.0,
            ),
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(()=>itemCount--);
                }
            ) :new Container(),

            new Text(itemCount.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

            new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 30.0,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() => itemCount++);
            }
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Now how can I pass this data of counter for each product individually  so that I can know which product was selected how many times to the class where I am calling like this.

```
child: new ListView(
             children: new List.generate(1, (i)=> Counter()
    )
```

Comment: Unclear. What do yo want ?

Comment: I am asking whenever a user clicks the + and - button here, the value of counter increases or decreases. Now I am calling this Widget inside another Widget, where a list of + and - is created infront of each product. How can I pass the counter value of each product to that Main class inside which this Widget is being called?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that. My recommended approach is to have the parent widget store the master state and by passing its  event handler to the child one as a reference and will make child update the method when its required.

So on the parent widget, you can do this

```
  var cart = List<Item>; // Create a model where you can store the items 

  void _handleCartChanges(Item newValue) {
    setState(() {
      cart.addValue(newValue) // do your stuff with the newvalue 
    });
  }

child: new ListView(
             children: new List.generate(1, (i)=> Counter(onPressed:_handleCartChanges)
    )
```

And now you can call the `onPressed` of the parent to notify the changes

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  Counter({Key key,  @required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool active;
  final ValueChanged<Item> onPressed;

  void _handlePress(int value) {  
    var item = Item(...) // create an item with the new vlaues
    onPressed(item); // and pass it
  }
```

so whenever you set the counter value, notify the parent as well by

```
 onPressed: (){
                  setState(()=>itemCount--);
                  _handlePress(itemCount) // call the parent 
                }
```

This is not a working code, but now you have the idea how to pass the state between parent and child.

Comment: Thank You for the solution. I'll try this and If it solves my problem I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Can you help me in figuring out how can I pass the index of each list tile? As you know I am creating this add and remove tile with each product. So if I need to create that Product, then I need to know of which index this tile is. How can I pass the index in the constructor then along with onPressed?

Comment: you can do this 
`class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  Counter({Key key,  @required this.onPressed, @required this.index})  : super(key: key);
final int index;
` 
and pass the index along in counter 
`children: new List.generate(1, (i)=> Counter(onPressed:_handleCartChanges,index:i)`

Comment: too many positional arguments, 0 required 1 found error as soon as I do this.